# Look for percentage of characters in a word/phrase within a block of text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Looking to create a condition to look for a % of characters in every word within a block of text. I'm thinking regexp_matches might be what I need but I'm not sure how to code it to look for a % occurrence for each word/phrase.

In the past I've used this below to pinpoint spaces within the entire block of text and then calculate a % for that over the length of the block:

```
(select count(*) from regexp_matches(table.blocktext, ' ', 'gi')
```

For instance each block of text could be say 100 to 1000 characters (a paragraph or two). And within those characters I want to say for example for every word do they have an 80% or more occurrence of the same character (could be a letter, number or anything else). So I'm not telling it the character just saying any character that constitutes 80% or more of the word/phrase. I also think I'd have to add a length condition so that it avoid shorter popular words where this might be common (like 'woohoo' etc). So maybe a length condition of 8 or more as well.

I'm hoping this is possible within Postgres, although I haven't managed to find any examples in my searches so far. Any assistance would be much appreciated and many thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I don't think this is even possible with regex; let alone practical. But after a quick bit of research, it seems you may be able to do this with a [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING)?

Comment: Thank you Tom, you are right although I managed to get a version working with Erwin's help below, it was never going to be fast. I have never used full text searches before so will be learning about that next. Thank again for posting some feedback, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
SELECT c, count(*) AS ct, (count(*) * 100) / length($1) AS pct
FROM   unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c
WHERE  length($1) > 7  -- maybe a length condition of 8 or more
GROUP  BY 1 
HAVING count(*) > (length($1) * 80) / 100  -- 80 is your % threshold
ORDER  BY 2 DESC;
```

`$1` being the string to be analyzed.

Returns characters that make up more than 80 percent of the given text. Can only be a single row for percentages 50 and above, obviously. Or nothing if no character is used frequently enough.

`(count(*) * 100) / length($1)` is just the fastest way to round and calculate with integer division. If you want precise results use `count(*) >= (length($1) * 80) / 100.0` instead (also note `>=` here). (`100.0` coerces the result of the calculation to be `numeric` and precise.)

You can easily wrap this into a function or prepared statement and pass string and percentage as parameters. Like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_char_pct(_word text, _pct int)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array(_word, NULL)) c
   GROUP  BY c 
   HAVING count(*) > (length(_word) * _pct) / 100
   )
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

*"If there is a single word in the given document with more than 7 characters and a character percentage below given threshold, return `false`. Else `true`"*

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array('1000000000000z abc 1234567890', ' ')) word
   WHERE  length(word) > 7
   AND    NOT f_char_pct(word, 80)
   );
```

Returns **`false`**.
Returns **`true`** for '1000000000000z abc 2222222' because 'abc' is ignored and the other two words have > 80 % of the same char.
Returns `false` for NULL input btw.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9c73b40feac5f6a159483c2b2f15dc97)*

You can also wrap the whole thing in a single function ...

`unnest(string_to_array($1, ' '))` splits *words* at every space. More sophisticated definitions are possible. You might use the text search infrastructure. Consider:

- [Finding the most commonly used non-stop words in a column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145016/finding-the-most-commonly-used-non-stop-words-in-a-column/186754)

---

BTW, I would replace your simple count:

```
select count(*) from regexp_matches(table.blocktext, ' ', 'gi')
```

.. with this equivalent, but much faster one:

```
SELECT length(table.blocktext) - length(replace(table.blocktext, ' ', ''))
```

Regular expression functions are powerful, but for a price. And the aggregation step makes it much more expensive yet. Related:

- [GROUP BY or COUNT Like Field Values - UNPIVOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226931/group-by-or-count-like-field-values-unpivot/8228041#8228041)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I had some issues getting the 'FROM unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c' to work, however I modified the code slightly and used a CTE style and managed to get something working in the end. The unnest(string_to_array()) was definitely the key so thank you for providing that, as without it I would have had nothing to go on. Also than k you for providing the equivalent and much faster  'SELECT length(table.blocktext) - length(replace(table.blocktext, ' ', ''))'. I ended up using this as well successfully on some related queries...

Comment: I haven't really explored wrapping of functions as yet, thank you for providing that info though, there are a lot of new things here which I will certainly used to build my knowledge on. The output is good now so I will mark this one as solved. I'm looking to do a rewrite in AWS as this would help the processing time, I will post another question shortly on that in case you have any ideas. But thanks again, really very much appreciated for your thorough and detailed answer.